# AWS Device Farm XCTest UI generated .xctestrun file is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, aws-device-farm

Device Farm generates a .xctestrun file and the location is stored at `$DEVICEFARM_XCUITESTRUN_FILE`. However, my test fails *everytime*

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace temporary with scheme Transient Testing.
    Reason: There are no test bundles available to test.
    Recovery suggestion: Ensure that all package dependencies have resolved and that there are no missing test bundles in the active scheme or test plan.
```

I print out the `.xctestrun` file in the yaml file and see that it's contents are not in the same format as the `.xctestrun` file created by Xcode during my build. Specifically the top-level object of the generated file shows up as a child in the Xcode file with the path `TestConfigurations/TestTargets`. The generated file is missing lots of top level objects like `TestConfigurations`, `ContainerInfo`, `TestPlan`, and `CodeCoverageBuildableInfos`.

Has anyone had success running iOS UI Tests in a custom environment using the generated `.xctestrun` file? According to the `man xcodebuild.xctestrun` output, the generated file is not in the correct format.

I've tried downloading a copy of the xctestrun file and using it locally and the tests also fail. I am able to successfully run the test locally when using the `.xctestrun` file created by Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this work I had to bypass all the automatic stuff that Device Farm does. I upload my own `.xctestrun` file instead of using the one generated by Device Farm. Then in my YAML test spec, I create a folder `/tmp/root` and copy my `.xctestrun` file into it. Then I create `/tmp/root/Debug-iphoneos` and copy both my app and test package `.app` files into that folder. This mimics my local environment exactly, and it successfully runs the test